# Подскажите как найти совпадение в массиве

Tags: c#

Всем здравствуйте, есть у меня массив номер 1 rubmass. В его основе лежит класс с двумя параметрами.
Есть так же массив номер 2 massstring, простой текстовый, в котором содержится строки. Как мне с помощью Linq или как то иначе сделать новый массив Lis , в котором будет только те элементы первого массива , которые соответствуют текстовым строкам массива номер 2.
Вот что у меня.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Rubrics> Lis=new List<Rubrics>();

            Rubrics[] rubmass=new Rubrics[5];
            rubmass[0] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя1", UrlRubrik = "www1"};
            rubmass[1] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя2", UrlRubrik = "www2" };
            rubmass[2] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя3", UrlRubrik = "www3" };
            rubmass[3] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя4", UrlRubrik = "www4" };

            string[] massstring=new string[2];
            massstring[0] = "Имя1";
            massstring[1] = "Имя2";


            foreach (var item in massstring)
            {
                var enumerable = rubmass.Where(x => x.Equals(item));
                foreach (var rubrics in enumerable) Lis.Add(rubrics);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",Lis));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

То есть на выходе я должен получить  rubmass[0] и rubmass[1].

ну и сам класс

```
 public   class Rubrics
    {
        public string NameRubrik { get; set; }
        public object UrlRubrik { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: типа `var result = rubmass.Where(x=>massstring.Contains(x.NameRubrik)).ToArray();` ?

Comment: @tym32167 в строке 28 ошибка вываливается, System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: В том, что вы написали, но нигде не показали, вывалилась ошибка в строке 28, и вы это пишете под кодом без нумерации строк? :)

Comment: @tym32167 )) да уж, но почему то компилятор говорит, что в вашем варианте x =null

Comment: Наверное потому, что вы создали массив на 5 элементов `new Rubrics[5]` - а заполнили только 4 элемента

Comment: Спасибо заработало

Comment: добавил ответом

Comment: а вам не проще будет использовать в вашем случае Dictonary?

Comment: @Monomax на входе именно таке данные, а про словарь да было бы проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием LINQ

```
var result = rubmass.Where(x=>massstring.Contains(x.NameRubrik)).ToArray();
```

Перепишем ваш код

```
Rubrics[] rubmass = new Rubrics[5];
rubmass[0] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя1", UrlRubrik = "www1" };
rubmass[1] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя2", UrlRubrik = "www2" };
rubmass[2] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя3", UrlRubrik = "www3" };
rubmass[3] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя4", UrlRubrik = "www4" };
rubmass[4] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя5", UrlRubrik = "www5" };

string[] massstring = new string[2];
massstring[0] = "Имя1";
massstring[1] = "Имя2";

var result = rubmass.Where(x=>massstring.Contains(x.NameRubrik)).ToArray();


foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.NameRubrik);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Вывод как ожидается

```
Имя1
Имя2
```

Comment: Проблема в выходной последовательности все равно  присутствует весь первый массив, а не только те элементы, которые мне нужны, вместо ожидаемых двух, их там 4

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Вы что то делаете не так. Добавил ещё кода в вопрос - на выходе 2 элемента

Comment: Но мне нужен массив на выходе, где будет rubmass[0] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя1", UrlRubrik = "www1" };
rubmass[1] = new Rubrics() { NameRubrik = "Имя2", UrlRubrik = "www2" };

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch именно этим и является `result` в моем примере